# Fraction.java program is not overloading, returning strange numbers

Tags: java

Firstly I have my main program that is calling to the Fraction.java, for the sake of this submission please assume all instances of "Fraction1" are actually "Fraction"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JursekGregWeek7
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    Fraction1 c, d, x; // Fraction objects

    System.out.println("Enter numerator; then denominator.");
    c = new Fraction1(stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt());
    c.printIt();

    System.out.println("Enter numerator; then denominator.");
    d = new Fraction1(stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt());
    d.printIt();

    x = new Fraction1(); // create a fraction for number 0

    System.out.println("Sum:");
    x.add(c).add(d);
    x.printIt();
    x.printAsDouble();

    x = new Fraction1(1, 1); // create a fraction for number 1

    System.out.println("Product:");
    x.multiply(c).multiply(d);
    x.printIt();
    x.printAsDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter numerator; then denominator.");
    x = new Fraction1(stdIn.nextInt(), stdIn.nextInt());
    x.printAsDouble();


    } // end main
}
```

Following is Fraction.java with added println's to determine was the values are at given points.

```
public class Fraction
{
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction()
    {    
        this.numerator = 1;
        this.denominator = 1;
    }   

    public Fraction(int n, int r)
    {
        this.numerator = n;
        this.denominator = r;
    }

    public Fraction add(Fraction f)
    {

        System.out.println(this.numerator + "banana");
        System.out.println(this.numerator + "asdfasdf");


        this.numerator = this.numerator * f.denominator + f.numerator * this.denominator;
        this.denominator = this.denominator * f.denominator;

        System.out.println(this.numerator + "this.numerator");
        System.out.println(this.denominator + "this.denominator");
        System.out.println(f.numerator + "f.numerator");
        System.out.println(f.denominator + "f.denominator");


        return this;
    }

    public Fraction multiply(Fraction f)   
    {
        this.numerator = this.numerator * f.numerator;
        this.denominator = this.denominator * f.denominator;   
        return this;
    }

    public void printIt()
    {
        System.out.println(this.numerator + "/" + this.denominator);
    }

    public void printAsDouble()
    {
        double d;
        d = (1.0 * this.numerator / this.denominator);
        System.out.println(d);
    }


}
```

The issue seems to be revolving around the public Fraction(), public Fraction(int n, int r) and the public Fraction add(Fraction f)

Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What SPECIFIC issue are you having?

Comment: Enter numerator; then denominator.
5
8
5/8
Enter numerator; then denominator.
4
10
4/10
Sum:
162/80
2.025
Product:
20/80
0.25

Comment: That is the output from terminal, sorry still learning how this website works. It decides that the sum of the numerators is, after determining the common denominator, is 80 higher than it should be. It seems that the numerators are either not holding their value as expected or they are being modified in some way in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You mess up here.

```
    this.numerator = this.numerator * f.denominator + f.numerator * this.denominator;
    this.denominator = this.denominator * f.denominator;
```

Use some temporary local variables (see code below).

2) 
Also this is not zero as your comment says :)

```
public Fraction()
{    
    this.numerator = 1;
    this.denominator = 1;
}
```

So these are the only two small fixes needed.

Here is your code fixed but think more about it 
(i.e. think why these fixes make it work).

```
public class Fraction
{
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction()
    {    
        this.numerator = 0;
        this.denominator = 1;
    }   

    public Fraction(int n, int r)
    {
        this.numerator = n;
        this.denominator = r;
    }

    public Fraction add(Fraction f)
    {

        // System.out.println(this.numerator);
        // System.out.println(this.numerator);

        int n = this.numerator;
        int d = this.denominator;

        this.numerator = n * f.denominator + f.numerator * d;
        this.denominator = d * f.denominator;

        // System.out.println(this.numerator + " : this.numerator");
        // System.out.println(this.denominator + " : this.denominator");
        // System.out.println(f.numerator + " : f.numerator");
        // System.out.println(f.denominator + " : f.denominator");

        return this;
    }

    public Fraction multiply(Fraction f)   
    {
        this.numerator = this.numerator * f.numerator;
        this.denominator = this.denominator * f.denominator;   
        return this;
    }

    public void printIt()
    {
        System.out.println(this.numerator + "/" + this.denominator);
    }

    public void printAsDouble()
    {
        double d;
        d = (1.0 * this.numerator / this.denominator);
        System.out.println(d);
    }


}
```

TEST:

```
Enter numerator; then denominator.
1
5
1/5
Enter numerator; then denominator.
1
6
1/6
Sum:
11/30
0.36666666666666664
Product:
1/30
0.03333333333333333
Enter numerator; then denominator.
4
12
0.3333333333333333
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Comment: So that looks exactly like mine does. What am I changing exactly? I'm very new to programming and this is the last project for this class (due in 5 hours).

Comment: When compiling this, it says that n and r are not declared and won't run?

Comment: `int n = this.numerator; int d = this.denominator;`

Comment: public Fraction(int n, int r)
    {
        this.numerator = n;
        this.denominator = r;
    }

Comment: It is in that section that it says n and r are not variables

Comment: I very much appreciate the assistance, I've spent time, 4 days in fact, on this program, I'm grasping at straws at this point with a looming deadline, that's why I'm here looking for any information to help

Comment: Well, OK. This code above is fine. See the test output. I wish I could help you a bit further but the error you give now is totally different and makes no sense to me. This is some minor stupid thing, so just copy all code in some new location and compile it. Also get rid of this Fraction/Fraction1 thing and use just Fraction.

Comment: @peter.petrov Ok, everything appears to be working now, I believe there was a corrupt portion of my original program that may have lingered into this one. I replaced the section you modified with your code and everything works great. I very much appreciate you assistance!

Comment: Yeah, I was just saying the same thing. NP, good luck! But spend some more time thinking why the two fixes did the trick. The second one of them is obvious btw.